# Executing the tags in a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, el

I have a JSP page,In that page,I am writing the following piece of code,

```xml
  <%@ taglib  uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<c:set var="variable" value="king"/>
<c:set var="abc" value="${variable}"/>
<s:set var="pqr" value="${variable}" />
```

the  tag yields the following exception,

> According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value
>   does not accept any expressions

I think, according to the tags designing wise of `<c:set>` and `<s:set>`, `<c:set>` accepts expression language in attribute and `<s:set>` does not EL in the  attribute.

If My assumption is correct,when parsing the  tag,parser throws the exception.

Because first if the file is parsed then, container can executes the EL even though when it is in `<c:set>` tag.

And hence when the page is parsing exception occurs by stopping the container to execute that code.

Am I right? Do I need the exact explanation?

Comment: What is `s`? What is `c`?

Comment: According to the error message, you're most probably dealing with Struts tags (as can be seen `<s:set>`) where `${variable}` is not allowed. It should be `%{variable}` instead. (It is hard to tell without looking into the rest of the code).

Comment: @Sotirios "c" represents JSTL wherea "S" represents struts2 tags.

Comment: @Tiny Why ${variable} is not allowed in <s:set...> when is allowed in <c:set...>,the design is like that of JSTL tags and struts tags?

Comment: May be because `${}` and `#{}` are already reserved in EL.